# Check NAnt version inside NAnt script

Tags: build, build-automation, nant

How to check **NAnt** version inside a **NAnt** script to display error?

For example my NAnt script works with NAnt version +0.92, so I need to display error if lesser version is being used by the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default property called `nant.version` which you can check against. This is now deprecated, you will see the rather verbose replacement in the warning message.

I don't know an easy way to enforce a minimum version check, but you could make something using the [version functions](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/functions/index.html#Version), or write your own `task` (it's not hard, using the `Version` class in dot net to compare them).